# Invalid token '=' in class, stuck, or interface member declaration in ASP.NET, C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public string Encoding { get; set; } = "Text";


public string Category { get; set; } = "Free";
```

I have an error of token, '='.. What should I do?

**Error : Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration**

Comment: What version of C#/compiler are you using?

Comment: The syntax you're using is new in C# 6.0 - you're probably using an older compiler version.

Comment: @RonBeyer I'm using VisualStudio 2013.

Comment: @Dai I think so, My compiler is old version.. So these days.. there are so many errors and problems...

Comment: @SethHong You need to be using a newer version, that syntax isn't supported in the version you are using.

Comment: @RonBeyer Thnx. but I have only 2013 lisence, The VisualStudio 2017 that can use for 30days finished, Can you recommend me free C# compiler?

Comment: @SethHong [Visual Studio Community 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/) is free.

Comment: @RonBeyer Thank you very much !, I did not know that. haha..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your compiler does not support that approach. try assigning values in a `constructor` as shared below.

```
public string Encoding { get; set; }
public string Category { get; set; } 

public NAMEOFClASS()
{
    this.Encoding="Text";
    this.Category="Free"

}
```

Comment: Any reason why this is getting downvoted?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. Probably due to people being jerkfaces

Comment: thanks for being curious about downvotes. you really made me happier.

Comment: @maccettura not my vote (but I support it). If author would even try searching for error they would find the current duplicate that indeed have better and more useful question. So providing less useful answer than existing answer is "this answer is not useful" in my book.

Comment: Thnx this answer helped me a lot, I'm first time using this website, this is my first question in this site, and I'm beginner in ASP.NET and C#.

Comment: @SethHong kindly mark the answer if I helped.

Comment: @AayQue Can you tell me how to mark? , I'm first time using this. sorry.

Comment: @SethHong Hit the green tick under the count of votes.

Comment: @AayQue I hit the green tick , is it working?

Comment: It worked 100%. thanks @SethHong

Comment: @AayQue Thnx, have a good day.